# Why does ThenBy raise an exception in the following case?

Tags: vb.net, .net-4.5

I am using .NET 4.5 and I would like to understand the following:

If I execute this everything works as expected:

```
  Dim lst = Enumerable.Range(1, 10)
  Dim lstOrdered = lst.OrderBy(Function(i) i Mod 2)
  Dim lst2 = lstOrdered.ThenBy(Function(i) -i)
```

However, the following raises a `System.MissingMemberException`

```
  Dim lst = Enumerable.Range(1, 10)
  Dim lstOrdered
  lstOrdered = lst.OrderBy(Function(i) i Mod 2)
  Dim lst2 = lstOrdered.ThenBy(Function(i) -i)
```

In the real code, we have to dynamically apply sometimes OrderBy and sometimes OrderByDescending and then dymaically continue with ThenBy and ThenByDescending. That's why I would like to declare it first.

Also note that the production code contains anonymous objects instead of integers.

**EDIT**

The following code it's closer to production and I don't seem to manage adapting to the provided answer. It compiles but throws an execution error.

```
Dim lst = Enumerable.Range(1, 10).Select(Function(i) New With {.a = "foo", .b = i Mod 2, .c = -i})
Dim lstOrdered As IOrderedEnumerable(Of Object)
lstOrdered = lst.OrderBy(Function(i) i.b)
Dim lst2 = lstOrdered.ThenBy(Function(i) i.c)
```

The error sais the following

```
Unable to cast object of type 'System.Linq.OrderedEnumerable`2[VB$AnonymousType_3`3[System.String,System.Int32,System.Int32],System.Int32]' to type 'System.Linq.IOrderedEnumerable`1[System.Object]'
```

Answer (score 3):

In your second example, you didn't declare a type for `lstOrdered`. It should work if you change the second line to

```
Dim lstOrdered As IOrderedEnumerable(Of Integer)
```

Set `Option Strict On` to catch these errors at compile time. You can make the statement `Option Strict On` the first one in your code file, set that option as the default in Test|Options|Environment|Projects and Solutions|VB Defaults.

Comment: what if instead of `Integer` I have anonymous objects?

Comment: @AsierAzkuenaga You can always do what I did. Write the code as in your first example, then hover over `lstOrderered` in the second statement and let the IDE tell you what type it has inferred for that variable. That is the type to use in the `Dim` statement.

Comment: how to declare `OrderedEnumerable(Of VB$AnonymousType_3(Of Object,Object),Object)` though?

Comment: @AsierAzkuenaga Perhaps you should edit your question to show what you want.